# In Java, repaint() doesn't call paintcomponent()

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

For a homework assignment I have to make a Java program that draws a red circle on a jframe when clicking a "start" button. When clicking the button, the method `setSmallCircle` is called. This does work, but inside this method I'm making a calling `repaint()`, but this doesn't seem to call the `paintComponent` method.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class ReactionPanel extends JPanel {
  Color color;
  int size;
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("paintcomp 1");
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("paintcomp 2");
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, size, size);
  }
  public void setSmallCircle(Color c){
    color = c;
    size = 10;
    System.out.println("drawing");
    repaint();
    System.out.println("repaint called");
  }
}
```

The method `setSmallCircle(Color.red)` is called by some other class. Does anyone know why the "repaint()" isn't drawing a red circle?

Comment: please add the corresponding calling code of `setSmalleCircle` too

Comment: How big is your jpanel?  Could it be that it is smaller than 200x200?

Comment: Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem - the reason most probably is in the code you are _not_ showing.

Answer (score 1):

Any update to the painting of swing component should be inside [EDT (eevent dispatch thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). However while experimenting following portion:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("paintcomp 1");

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(color);
    System.out.println(color); // print color as null
    g.fillOval(20, 20, size, size); // printing size as 0

    System.out.println(size);

  }
```

updating `color` and `size` in `setSmallCircle()` is not taking effect !!  `paintComponent` seems to keep using the old value, instead of updated value.

Comment: _updating color and size in setSmallCircle() is not taking effect_ can't be, can it :_)

Comment: i myself is confused here. can please shade some light on my thoughts. a little hint will work. probably i have missed something about paintComponent even though i have invested more than 3 months on doing advanced graphics in it. :(

Comment: can't without seeing a SSCCE :-)

Comment: uhh i have asked that too. :)